# DWR call throws "Failed to read input" in IE8, appearing too frequent

Tags: java, apache, internet-explorer-8, tomcat7, dwr

This issue occurs in `IE8` only, On browser it throws `http 502 error` ,while in `apache` it throws `http 103` & my application breaks due to this error

After adding sysout in `dwr jar` i got the following logs:

```
    DWR Exception in ParsePost Data Failed to read input
    java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:268)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.ParseUtil.parsePost(ParseUtil.java:65)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.Batch.<init>(Batch.java:58)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallMarshaller.marshallInbound(BaseCallMarshaller.java:76)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:42)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.zycus.icontract.common.IContractSessionValidationOpenXavaFilter.doFilter(IContractSessionValidationOpenXavaFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    DWR Excpetion in MarshallInbound 
    org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerException: Failed to read input
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.ParseUtil.parsePost(ParseUtil.java:110)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.Batch.<init>(Batch.java:58)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallMarshaller.marshallInbound(BaseCallMarshaller.java:76)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:42)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.zycus.icontract.common.IContractSessionValidationOpenXavaFilter.doFilter(IContractSessionValidationOpenXavaFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:268)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.ParseUtil.parsePost(ParseUtil.java:65)
        ... 25 more

Inside marshallException
Exiting from marshallException
Returning from PlainCallHandler
```

I found few solution for the above issue :

1)Increase `keepAliveTimout` in apache

2)Change the way of reading input in `ParseUtil` class of `dwr jar` 
from

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));
```

to

```
BufferedReader in = req.getReader();
```

But issue is still reproducible in `IE8`

I also tried to give alert message `"Internal Server Error. Please Try Again"` when this exception occur but alert is not coming. I have done changes in `dwr-engine.js` for showing alert message

Comment: when does this exception comes.. what are u actually trying to actually achieve out of this.. plz elaborate ur issue

Comment: This issue occurs when continuously making dwr calls in IE8

Comment: `http://www.coderanch.com/t/610812/Performance/java/DWR-call-throws-Failed-read#2790330`

Comment: exception change when the way reading input change from `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));` to `BufferedReader in = req.getReader();`

Comment: Exception ::  `org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerException: Failed to read input
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.ParseUtil.parsePost(ParseUtil.java:112)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.Batch.<init>(Batch.java:58)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallMarshaller.marshallInbound(BaseCallMarshaller.java:76)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:43)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:99)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:145)`

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket read failed
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:313)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.receive(AjpProcessor.java:331)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:576)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1027)`

Comment: after DWR jar debugging i got following scenario:-> for 5 min it stuck on `BufferedReader in = req.getReader();`  after words apache breaks the connection & throws 103 error

Comment: what version of DWR are you using?

Comment: Please also give more details about what you are doing to trigger this error.  What JavaScript are you executing in the browser when this happens?

Comment: DWR version 2 in openxava framework

Comment: This IE8 issue, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895954 , only the header data is posted when re-post the request.. as per investigation, i am still looking for soluation...

Answer (score 0):

1)Increase keepAliveTimout in apache

2)Change the way of reading input in ParseUtil class of dwr jar